# Redirecting a URL with an action parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've disabled password resetting for a CMS however if anyone knows the necessary URL, they can still arrive at an obsolete password reset form:

```
www.mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword
```

Should a user manually type this URL, I'd like the URL to automatically redirect to:

```
www.mysite.com/wp-login.php
```

I'm ultimately trying to prevent the action parameter in the URL from triggering the password reset form.

Would I be correct in this instance to [use a 301 redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) or is there a more advisable approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would indeed use a 301 redirect, but you don't need the plugin you linked to. You could add the following code to your `functions.php`.

```
function disable_lost_password() {
    if ( in_array( $_GET['action'], array('lostpassword', 'retrievepassword') ) ) {
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url(), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( "init", "disable_lost_password" );
```

Note that you also need to check for the `retrievepassword` action.

Comment: Third bracket is missing but yes, this correctly redirects and not as overkill as a plugin. The resulting URL contains a  `redirect_to=` parameter leading to the lost password page which I presume will bounce to `www.example.com/wp-login.php` and in turn, whatever I've set post log-in redirects to. I.e. Edit profile page, home page etc. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I added the missing bracket, thanks! This code would redirect immediately to the /wp-admin url when someone manually type the lostpassword url.

Comment: Would `add_action('init','somefunctionname'); somefunctionname(){/*The code in your answer*/}`  eliminate the need for your code being added to the top of functions.php? Not a requirement, just curious.

Comment: I couldn't find a filter that is able to update the action in the url. But maybe I overlooked it? If someone knows a filter to do this, I would gladly update my answer. EDIT: I misread your comment, the init hook would be perfect for this. In the docs they advice to use this hook. I'll update my answer.

Comment: FYI: Can be further constrained using isset(): http://pastebin.com/rYVkAQXN. Furthermore, I've just discovered [login_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_init/) exists.